# How to add a calculated member based on group / subgroups

Tags: mdx

*Hi, i have a new challenge for MDX.
i defined this mdx:*

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[SubGroupID] AS 
    [Dim Customer].[Customer SubGroup ID].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 
  MEMBER [Measures].[MainGroupID] AS 
    [Dim Customer].[Customer MainGroup ID].CurrentMember.Member_Caption 

SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
     [Measures].[SubGroupID],
     [Measures].[MainGroupID],
     [Measures.[SalesAmount]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {
        [Dim Customer].[Customer ID].[Customer ID].MEMBERS * 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].MEMBERS
    }
  DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
    MEMBER_CAPTION
   ,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME
   ON ROWS
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    {
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]
      : 
        [Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Date].&[2015-01-05T00:00:00]
    } ON COLUMNS
  FROM [Cube]
);
```

*The result shows me the rowset below:*

CustomerID / Date / SubGroupID /  MainGroupID /  SalesAmount

1 / 1.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  11
1 / 2.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  12
1 / 3.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  13
1 / 4.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  14
1 / 5.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  15
2 / 1.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  16
2 / 2.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  17
2 / 3.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  18
2 / 4.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  19
2 / 5.1.2015 /  SG1  / MG1 /  20
3 / 1.1.2015 /  SG12 / MG1 /  21
3 / 2.1.2015 /  SG12 / MG1 /  22
3 / 3.1.2015 /  SG12 / MG1 /  23
3 / 4.1.2015 /  SG12 / MG1 /  24
3 / 5.1.2015 /  SG12 / MG1 /  25
4 / 1.1.2015 /  SG1  / G21 /  26
4 / 2.1.2015 /  SG1  / G21 /  27
4 / 3.1.2015 /  SG1  / G21 /  28
4 / 4.1.2015 /  SG1  / G21 /  29
4 / 5.1.2015 /  SG1  / G21 /  30

*now i want two new colums which shows me the summary per day for subgroup and maingroup:*
*below the result set with the 2 new columns and how i´like to calculate*

CustomerID / Date / SubGroupID / MainGroupID /  SalesAmount / SalesAmountSubGroup in MainGroup / SalesAmountMainGroup /

1 / 1.1.2015 / SG1  / MG1  / 11 / x = 11 + 16 / y = 11 + 16 + 21
1 / 2.1.2015 / SG1  / MG1  / 12 / x = 12 + 17 / y = 12 + 17 + 22
.
.
3 / 1.1.2015 / SG12 / MG1 / 21 / x = 21   / y = 11 + 16 + 21
3 / 2.1.2015 / SG12 / MG1 / 22 / x = 22   / y = 12 + 17 + 22
.
.
4 / 1.1.2015 / SG1  / MG21 / 26 / x = 26      / y = 26
4 / 2.1.2015 / SG1  / MG21 / 27 / x = 27      / y = 27
.
.

*i´m sure sombody has an idea.
Thanks in advance*

Comment: why do you have `Name1` in the first row of your desired result set and yet it needs to sum ( 11 + 16) and (11 + 16 + 21) which relate to more than just `Name1` ?

Comment: Are you trying to eliminate some of the rows or is it just an example?

Comment: BTW, totally cool way to seduce people into solving your question by starting  with *"Hi, i have a new challenge for MDX"* :-)

Comment: i deleted the "name-colums" for a better description, 
i also improved the formula of the second new colum.

for a better explanation:
Each Customer (e.g. #1 - #4) has a salesamount per day. Each Customer belongs to a subgroup (e.g. category)  and to a maingroup (e.g. country).

X should be the summary per date for all cutomers of the same subgroup and in the same maingroup 
y should be the summary per date for all customer of the same maingroup 

Thanks

Comment: @Katharina321 something happened to your script when editing - did you delete too much, or not enough ?!